# Are purchase recommendations for airsoft guns on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've had a look and seen that airsoft in general is considered a sport in this site and questions about it are accepted. I'm just wondering, specifically, if purchase recommendations are on-topic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not; [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is a general guideline across the network so anything where you're asking anything even vaguely similar to "Should I buy specific model X or specific model Y?" is off-topic.

What *might* be on topic is a question asking how to choose what to buy; I personally know nothing about airsoft so can't give a good example there, but something like "How do I choose between materials for a badminton racket?", where answers could guide people to the general idea that "steel rackets are cheaper (and heavier), graphite rackets are more expensive (and lighter)".

To borrow what I think is an excellent answer from our friends over at Photography SE: [Why is there so much hostility to 'what should I buy' and 'shopping' questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/why-is-there-so-much-hostility-to-what-should-i-buy-and-shopping-questions/3958#3958)

(Full disclosure: I am also a moderator at Photography SE, but that answer was written well before I was involved)

Comment: So, if i'm understanding correctly, for my question to hopefully be on-topic, I should ask in a way that can be answered with facts and/or statistics. To borrow from your example, something like "how should I choose between airsoft firing mechanisms?", which could be answered with pros and cons of each, and such an answer could be useful to others besides me.

Comment: Yes - but ideally also in a way that means the answer won't be out of date next year when there are different models on the market. "Airsoft gun X costs $Y at store Z" is a fact - but just not a useful one next year when gun X has been replaced by gun X2 and store Z might have closed down. "How to choose between airsoft firing mechanisms" sounds like a good question to me though.

Comment: OK, that's good. Getting pros and cons of the different mechanisms so I can apply that to my skill level and specific needs was pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: I look forward to the question (but won't be answering it due to my aforementioned lack of knowledge!)